# jest.setMock not working for installed dependencies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am having trouble using `jest.setMock` with installed dependencies

So, I have a feature to test which requires `my-module` dependency:

```
// my-module/index.js

import { hello } from 'my-dep';
export const doSomething = () => {
  return hello();
};

// my-dep
// location: my-module/node_modules/my-dep/index.js

export const hello = () => {
  return 'dude';
};
```

I have "npm linked" the `my-module` in my `app`:

```
cd my-module
npm link
cd app
npm link my-module
```

I wrote a test file as follows:

```
// app/feature.test.js

jest.setMock('my-dep', {
  hello: () => 'world'
});

const { doSomething } = require('my-module');

it('should return dude', () => {
  expect(doSomething()).toBe('dude');
});
```

**I don't understand why mocking `my-dep` did not work and called the actual `hello()` function.**

When I tried using the `my-module` file as relative import & installed `my-dep` dependency, the mocking worked:

```
// app/feature.test.js

jest.setMock('my-dep', {
  hello: () => 'world'
});

const { doSomething } = require('./my-module');

it('should return world', () => {
  expect(doSomething()).toBe('world');
});
```

What am I missing here?

#### Environment:

Binaries:

- Node: 8.9.4
- Yarn: 1.3.2
- npm: 5.6.0

npmPackages:

- jest: ^22.4.3 => 22.4.3

#### Some related issues:

1. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/701
2. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/796

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely caused by the module loading order, but I'm not sure how changing from `my-module` to `./my-module` changes it. I'd love to see the console output after adding `console.log(require('path').join(__dirname, __filename))` to the top of `my-module` and `my-dep`.

[This comment in the Jest issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/796#issuecomment-196417921) you shared indicates that `jest.setMock` isn't hoisted before your `import` statements. If you switch it to use [`jest.mock`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) that is hoisted, does it work?

```
jest.mock('my-dep', () => ({
  hello: () => 'world'
}));
```

The Jest docs on manual mocks mention hoisting in [this note](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#using-with-es-module-imports):

> If you're using ES module imports then you'll normally be inclined to put your import statements at the top of the test file. But often you need to instruct Jest to use a mock before modules use it. For this reason, Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module (before any imports).

For more about hoisting in JavaScript, refer to [You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures - Chapter 4: Hoisting](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md)

Comment: I saw that comment too. And that is the reason I `require`ed `my-module` in my test cases to make sure `jest.setMock` is done beforehand. And I also tried using `jest.mock`. That doesn't help either.